# Bazel build rules for BLAS & LAPACK

Tags: lapack, blas, bazel

I have not found any project/repo providing Bazel build rules for Blas or Lapack. 
This is quite unfortunate as these tools are often the primary libraries one must use for project oriented towards numerical computations.
Does such thing already exist somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

No BUILD files yet...

However, a quick fix if you want to use already installed `Blas` or `Lapack` libs is to add a line like this one (according to the installed libs on your computer):

```
build --linkopt="-llapacke -llapack -lblas"
```

in your `bazel.rc` file (in the `tools/` directory):

```
YourBazelProject/.

├── ...
├── WORKSPACE
└── tools
     └── bazel.rc
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of BUILD files for these libraries either.

If you do create them, sharing them publicly or trying to submit them upstream (in the library code) will be a great way for others to benefit from your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Searched the same thing in 2023 and found this thread.  There still doesn't seem to be any options.  So, I wrote build rules for [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS).  I have tested them on a Windows 10 system and Ubuntu system.

https://github.com/phpisciuneri/rules_openblas/releases/tag/v0.1.1

Any comments are welcome.